# How do I build a complex filter for Flask-Restless when using Requests?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, flask-restless

I want to make a complex query to a Flask-Restless api using Requests.  I am not sure how to build the following [query from the examples](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchformat.html#examples) with Requests.  How do I make this query?

> ```
> GET /api/person?q={"filters":[{"name":"age","op":"ge","val":10}]} HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Flask-Restless expects a query string in JSON format.  The example given is a dictionary with a list of filters, each filter being another dictionary.  Build your query structure, dump it to JSON, then make the query with Requests.

```
import json
q = {'filters': [{'name': 'age', 'op': 'ge', 'val': 10}]}
r = requests.get('http://example.com', params={'q': json.dumps(q)})
```